# How to delete double quotes from the beginning and the end of a string

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have strings which contain double quotes like this one:

```
"[{"clientid":"*", "identityzone":"*"}]"
```

I would like to use `set` or `grep` to delete the double quotes at the beginning and at the end of it, the output should look like :

```
[{"clientid":"*", "identityzone":"*"}]
```

I have used : `sed -e 's/\"//g'` but this deletes all the `"` in a string

Comment: `sed -i.bak -E 's/^"|"$//g' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use line anchors

```
$ echo '"[{"clientid":"*", "identityzone":"*"}]"' | sed 's/^"//; s/"$//'
[{"clientid":"*", "identityzone":"*"}]
```

- `^"` match `"` only at start of line
- `"$` match `"` only at end of line
- You can also combine them using `|` as `sed 's/^"\|"$//g'`
- See [Overview of basic regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

easy:

```
sed 's/^\"\(.*\)\"$/\1/g' <<<'"[{"clientid":"*", "identityzone":"*"}]"'
```